# Environment variables in LFTP script

Tags: bash, terminal, console, lftp

I am trying to run lftp with a script like so:

`$ lftp -f deploy.scp`

However I would like to use environment variables for l/p inside `deploy.scp` like so:

`open -u $FTP_USER,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST;`

Is that possible in any way? I have struck out finding any help in the man-pages.

Comment: I also didn't see anything in the man page for this. It wouldn't surprise me if it couldn't be done. If you can't/don't want to use the `-u` argument for this then you could consider modifying the file at runtime and/or using a here document `lftp -f - <<EOF open -u $FTP_USER,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST; $(cat deploy.scp) EOF` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you put this to last line of deploy.scp (*After bye command) :

```
open -u $FTP_USER,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST;
```

then you can use the following command :

```
lsftp -f deploy.scp `cat deploy.scp | tail -1`
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't make it work. It doesn't connect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
<deploy.scp xargs -l sh -c 'eval echo $0 $*' | lftp
```

or, to save some typing, make an alias, let's say

```
alias xv=$'xargs -l sh -c \'eval echo $0 $*\''
```

and then

```
xv <deploy.scp | lftp
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it requires the additional tool `envsubst`, this worked for me via [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)

```bash
lftp -f <(envsubst < lftp_commands.txt)
```

assuming I've set those environment variables and `lftp_commands.txt` contains something like

```
open --user $FTP_USER --password $FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST
put example.txt
exit
```